# VBA logic to generate a string with appropriate commas and "and" for Array of 5 strings

Tags: arrays, string, vba

I have an array of 5 strings: Introtext2arr(One, Two, Three, Four, Five), each string in the array has a boolean array to say if the string exists and should get printed: checkBoxarr(1 to 5)

If checkedBoxarr(One, Three, Five) are checked as True, then the end result should print "One, Three, and Five."

If checkedBoxarr(One, Three) are checked as True, then the end result should print "One and Three."

I'm using a For i = 1 To 5 look with logic to iterate down to check if the array position is true, then print it and check the array count against logic to add a comma, and, and a period to my final string.

I keep working but keep running into bugs.

Count is an integer that = Count of checkedBoxarr(1 to 5).

my code is buggin on the count logic.

Current code:

```
'VARIABLES
Dim checkBoxarr(1 To 5) As Boolean
Introtext2arr = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")
IntroText2start = "The array contains"
IntroText2 = ""

For i = 1 To 5

    If checkBoxarr(i) = True Then
        IntroText2 = IntroText2 + Introtext2arr(i)
        Debug.Print Introtext2arr(i)
    End If

    If (i = Count) Then
        IntroText2 = IntroText2 + "."

    ElseIf (Count - i) = 1 Then                 'meaning it is at it's next to last phrase
        If Count = 2 Then                       'only 2 parts so only use " and "
            IntroText2 = IntroText2 + " and"
        Else                                    'more than 2 parts so we add the comma to the and
            IntroText2 = IntroText2 + ", and"
        End If

    ElseIf (Count - i > 1) Then                 'more than 2 parts, but we're not to the near end yet, so only add comma
        If checkBoxarr(i) = True Then
            IntroText2 = IntroText2 + ","
        End If


    End If

 Next

Selection.TypeText Text:=IntroText2start + IntroText2
```

I know the above is faulty because it'll print "Two, and Three. Five"  But it does at least check and print all five possible strings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA arrays are base-0 unless otherwise specified. Since you may not always control the base of the array, it's better to use the `LBOUND` and `UBOUND` functions, rather than assuming they are Base-1.

I would also caution against using the `+` operator for string concatenation, as a general rule, since it can easily be confused by mixed data types (i.e., `1 + "steve"` will yield a type mismatch error, `1 + 2` will give the result of `3` instead of `12`, etc.).

Rather than setting up all these conditions, just build a simple delimited string and replace the *last* instance of the delimiter with `, and`.

```
'Declare your variables properly
Dim checkBoxarr(1 To 5) As Boolean
Dim Introtext2Arr as Variant
Dim IntroText2Start As String
Dim IntroText2 as String

Introtext2arr = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")
IntroText2start = "The array contains"
IntroText2 = ""

For i = LBound(checkBoxarr) to UBound(checkBoxarr)
    'builds a simple delimited string
    'here you can omit the "= True" since this is a boolean test:
    If checkBoxarr(i) Then
        If IntroText2Start <> "" Then
            IntroText2start = IntroText2Start & ", " & IntroText2Arr(i)
        Else
            IntroText2start = IntroText2Arr(i)
        End If
    End If
 Next

 'Now, replace the last delimiter with the word "and ":
 IntroText2Start = Left(IntroText2Start, InstrRev(IntroText2Start, ",") -1) & _
                   "and " & _
                   Mid(IntroText2Start, InstrRev(IntroText2Start, ",") - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you David for the quick response. I'm reading up on InStrRev() and Left() / Mid(). Thanks for the idea of LBound and UBound. The first If needs checkBoxarr(i) = True Then, forgot the True. I'm still implementing it in my macro.

Comment: (One, Two, Four) yields:   The array contains, One, Two and , Four      which is almost exactly what I want minus the "and" and last comma placement.

Comment: `Mid(IntroText2Start, InstrRev(IntroText2Start, ",") - 1)`

Comment: the -1 just made text come back in. I gave up and just macro'd find "and, " and replaced with ", and". cheap workaround. also I found a bug. If you have only one boolean in the aray that's True, then the macro fails on :      Introtext2start = Left(Introtext2start, InStrRev(Introtext2start, ",") - 1) _
                    & " and" & Mid(Introtext2start, InStrRev(Introtext2start, ","))